# Jinja inside of Jinja double curly braces

Tags: python, jinja2

Dear fellow developers,

Here's a sample code

```
{% set title = "Mr." %}
{% set pname = "John" %}
{% set middle_name = "Hayward" %}
{% set lname = "Citizen" %}
{% set display_name = "{{title}} {{pname}} {{middle_name}} {{lname}}" %}

<h4 class='prepared-for'><small>{{display_name}}</small></h4>
```

I have something like this. Please see, this display name is coming from the backend but just for the sake of simplicity, I'm setting it as a jinja variable for now.

Now having this structure, I'm getting `{{title}} {{pname}} {{middle_name}} {{lname}}` but I want this to replace the values being set in the variables.

Any ideas about how I should approach this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of a Jinja templating context you can just refer to variables by name. You don't need to nest the `{{..}}` markers.  Since you're building a string, you will need to use some style of variable substitution. For example:

```
{% set display_name = "{} {} {} {}".format(title, pname, middle_name, lname) %}
```

You could get the same result by using the string concatenation operator:

```
{% set display_name = title ~ " " ~ pname ~ " " ~ middle_name ~ " " ~ lname %}
```

Or using `printf` style formatting:

```
{% set display_name = "%s %s %s %s" % (title, pname, middle_name, lname) %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @larsks. It's a simple and clean solution I couldn't think of at the moment. Kudos!